# Inserir vídeo ou HTML ou JS externo em uma div

Tags: javascript, html, div

No site que estou desenvolvendo, gostaria de chamar um video externo dentro de uma `div`,  apenas usando a ID do video.

Exemplo: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJAwNkhbYWM`

No caso a ID do video é essa: `UJAwNkhbYWM`. Sempre que criar um post nesse website e tiver uma ID do youtube dentro da div o video apareceria.

Exemplo:

```
post

div class="UJAwNkhbYWM">/div

--------video--------------
```

Isso é possivel?

Ou fazer a mesma coisa com uma pagina HTML externa.

Exemplo:

```
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28064/inserir-vídeo-externo-em-uma-div
```

Apenas usando uma parte do link:  `questions/28064/inserir-vídeo-externo-em-uma-div` dentro da div mostraria a página.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Será que isso pode ajudá-lo? Em caso de dúvida me avise por favor. Para ver o resultado clique [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/SamirChaves/76emova3/1/)
.

***HTML***

```
<div id="video" class="UJAwNkhbYWM">
     <iframe width="854" height="510" id="caixa" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>     
</div>
```

**JavaScript Puro**

```
  var video = document.getElementById("video");
  var video = video.className;
  var iFrame = document.getElementById("caixa");
  iFrame.src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + video;
```

**JQuery**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var video = $("#video").attr('class');
    $('#caixa').attr('src', "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + video);
 });
```

Comment: Valeu me ajudou muito, estou tentando aprimora um script nessa pergunta  http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28721/editar-script-para-funciona-em-div poderia da uma olghada

Comment: Conselho: Sempre que a resposta a sua pergunta, for o que você queria, dê um upVote ou a favorite, para que os outros usuários tenham em mente que a pergunta já está respondida como deveria. Bem vindo ao StackOverFlow

Comment: Assim que puder lhe ajudarei, com sua dúvida em relação a pergunta.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer em jQuery usando o atributo data.

Por exemplo, seu html ficaria assim:

```
<div class="video" data-id="UJAwNkhbYWM"></div>
```

E seu jQuery ficaria:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var id = $('.video').data('id');
    $('.video').html('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + id +'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
});
```

O id do vídeo vai no atributo "data-id" referenciado no HTML e o jQuery faz o resto do trabalho para ler e colocar o frame do vídeo dentro da própria div.

Comment: Me ajudou muito,  poderia me ajuda com essa outra pergunta,  http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28721/editar-script-para-funciona-em-div

Answer (score 3):

Para todos os vídeos da pagina funcionarem corretamente, deve ser assim:

**jquery:**

```
$('[data-id]').each(function(){
    $(this).html( '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + $(this).data('id') +'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
});
```

**html:**

```
<div data-id="UJAwNkhbYWM"></div>

<div data-id="XxVg_s8xAms"></div>
```

Comment: Poderia me ajuda nessa outra pergunta  http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28721/editar-script-para-funciona-em-div